# Certbot with HSTS causes handshake failure?

Tags: ssl, webserver, certbot

I've been using Certbot for years with few issues. However, I recently got a `.app` domain, which has HSTS enabled by default.

When I go through the usual Certbot setup using `certbot certonly --manual`, I get "remote error: tls: handshake failure".

When I run `wget http://example.app/.well-known/acme-challenge/123 --no-check-certificate`, I get:

```
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Is this issue because of HSTS or something else?

Comment: for wget --no-hsts will disable hsts check or remove specific host in ~/.wget-hsts.